# Passing a List<string[]> into a method accepting string[] as parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, methods, parameter-passing

Guys I am passing some parameter to a new window of a WPF application as follows

```
List<string[]> liststat = conf.getlistbytype(type);
if ((liststat == null) || (liststat.Count == 0))
{
    MessageBox.Show("There is no stat of that type in this stat server");
}
else
{
    CalculatedStat3 prompt = new CalculatedStat3(statwin, conf, liststat, this);
    prompt.Show();
```

However the construtor of the target page is as

```
 public CalculatedStat3(statwindow statwin, ConfigLayer conf, string[] statsname, CalculatedStat2 backscreen)
 {
 }
```

What should I do to be able to rectify this as i am getting an error as

```
'RCCV_Version_2.CalculatedStat3.CalculatedStat3(RCCV_Version_2.statwindow, rmad_wpf_lib.ConfigLayer, string[], RCCV_Version_2.CalculatedStat2)' has some invalid arguments
```

Comment: There is a big difference between List<string[]> and string[]. you need a foreach loop that handles all the differente string[] under the list.

Answer (score 5):

First solution, get only first array

```
CalculatedStat3 prompt = new CalculatedStat3(statwin, conf, liststat.First(), this);
```

Second, flatten your collection

```
var stats = liststat.SelectMany(x=>x).ToArray();
CalculatedStat3 prompt = new CalculatedStat3(statwin, conf, stats, this);
```

In first solution you will get only first array of stats, in second one, you will get big array of concatenated all stats. I think that seconds solution meets your requirements.

Comment: yes it was the second solution that i was looking for. Thnx +1

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear which `string[]` you want to use for the constructor, so i just take the first:

```
else
{
   string[] firstStat = liststat.First();
   CalculatedStat3 prompt = new CalculatedStat3(statwin, conf, firstStat, this);
```

If you want to create multiple `CalculatedStat3`:

```
else
{
   CalculatedStat3[] allCalculatedStat3 = liststat
      .Select(s => new CalculatedStat3(statwin, conf, s, this))
      .ToArray();
   foreach(CalculatedStat3 stat in allCalculatedStat3)
       stat.Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also concatenate all the arrays as follows:

```
List<string> finalList = new List<string>();

foreach (string[] strings in liststat)
    finalList.AddRange(strings);

string[] finalArray = finalList.ToArray();
```

And then pass `finalArray` to the method.

---

This is the same that `daryal` is doing, just without LINQ. Do as you please.

Answer (score 0):

`liststat` is the list of string arrays not a single string array that `CalculatedStat3` method accepts that is why you are getting compilation error.

Either pass first element of list

```
CalculatedStat3 prompt = new CalculatedStat3(statwin, conf, liststat[0], this);
```

or change method to accept list of string arrays

```
public CalculatedStat3(statwindow statwin, ConfigLayer conf, List<string[]> statsname, CalculatedStat2 backscreen)
```

Select the solution that works best for you and your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((liststat == null) || (liststat.Count == 0))
{
    MessageBox.Show("There is no stat of that type in this stat server");
}
else
{
    var list = new List<string>();
    liststat.ForEach(q => list.AddRange(q));
    CalculatedStat3 prompt = new CalculatedStat3(statwin, conf, list.ToArray(), this);
    prompt.Show();
```

Comment: You need to pass `list.ToArray()` instead of `list`, because the method takes an `string[]`, not a `List<string>`.